Rename [mulan] → [mulan-1998]
According to the top-voted answer in the meta post Rules for multiple media using the same name:

if there are two films (or TV shows) with the same title, they should both (or all) have dates on the tags.

In line with this, I propose that the existing tag mulan (currently used for the 1998 animated Disney film) be renamed/merged to mulan-1998, since there is a 2020 live-action Disney film with the same name, "Mulan" (which has the mulan-2020 tag).
By appending the release year to the tag, it will help differentiate between the two films and maintain clarity when discussing or referencing either version of "Mulan".

There are, as you are not doubt aware, no less than 5 films called Mulan plus several animated films of the same name.
